# anchor id is not working in Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: html, google-chrome, href, mozilla

I have this in my page:

```
    <a href="#goto1"> Go to 1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#goto2"> Go to 2</a>
```

And this:

```
<p><h3>
<a id="goto1"></a>
This is one</h3>

<p><h3>
<a id="#goto2"></a>
This is two</h3>
```

Now, when I click on first link it goes to matching id and shows the paragraph but when I click on second link it doesn't do anything. I have a lot of similar links and about half of them not working the same way. I use Chrome Version 64.0.3282.140. The same problem with Mozilla.

IE 11 works fine.

Please advise.

Comment: You aren't closing your `<p>` tags.

Comment: @Turnip The `</p>` tags are implied.

Answer (score 0):

I should have paid more attention, the value for second id has # in it, it should not contain it. Interestingly, even if it is not proper way still it works in IE11. So it should be:

```
<p><h3>
<a id="goto2"></a>
This is two</h3>
```

Same way as in first link id.